# Is selenium used to automate the web application in remote desktop

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have tried the selenium IDE for record and play back options for test cases in web application in my computer , 
1) Is selenium IDE can also record the test cases using the remote deskop, if yes please provide the settings 
I was using that application by connecting to QA server using the VPN connection.
Is selenium can used to automate application in QA server ?

Answer (score 0):

No directly no.

You'd have to install the IDE and Firefox on the machine you are RDP'ing into.

After all, the IDE is tied into Firefox (it's a Firefox plugin), so you'd have to have it on whatever machine you are connecting to.

I would therefore suggest you look into WebDriver. It will give more flexibility over this kind of stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your support . But QA server belong to client where we do not have a right to install the selenium . please can you share any other approach that we can record and play using the IDE . here we can install the selenium only in our pc.

Comment: You will have to look into using `Webdriver` programmatic-ally. You will not be able to use the `IDE` in the manner you wish if you do not have the access to the client's system as described above.

Comment: Thanks , can you provide any link where can i gain knowledge of web driver and automate the web application.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following if using Perl

```
Selenium::Remote::Driver->new (
    'browser_name'       => $browser, 
    'remote_server_addr' => $host,
    'port'               => $port,
    'accept_ssl_certs'   => 1,
    'handlesAlerts'      => 1,
    'takesScreenshot'    => 0,
    'javascript'         => 1,
    'proxy'              => $proxy,
    'extra_capabilities' => $extra_capabilities,
);
```

Ref: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp